# pasar una función como parámetro de un constructor en ruby

Tags: poo, ruby

quisiera mandar una función como parámetro a una clase de Ruby y guardar tanto la función como su ejecución, pero no me las he ingeniado como hacerlo.

De momento he intentado esto:

```
def a(x,y)
   return x+y
end

class miClase
    def initialize(funcion, param1, param2)
       @fun=funcion
       @res=funcion.call(param1, param2)
    end
end
miClase=miClase.new(method(:a),4,3)

puts(miClase.res)
puts(miClase.fun(2,2))
```

y obtengo el siguiente error

> main.rb:5: class/module name must be CONSTANT

Salida que esperaría

> 7
>
> 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actualización**

Utilizando tu mismo código, podrías agregar el método `fun` para poder ejecutar nuevamente el método(función) guardado con los nuevos parámetros; por ejemplo:

```
def a(x,y)
  x + y
end

class MiClase
  attr_reader :res

  def initialize(funcion, param1, param2)
    @fun = funcion
    @res = @fun.call(param1, param2)
  end

  def fun(param1, param2)
    @fun.call(param1, param2)
  end
end

mi_clase = MiClase.new(method(:a), 4, 3)

puts mi_clase.res
#=> 7

puts mi_clase.fun(2, 2)
#=> 4
```

---

El error se debe a que las clases y módulos en ruby se deben escribir con la primer letra en mayúscula:

```
class MiClase
  # ...
end
```

---

El comportamiento que buscas me parece un poco extraño, sin embargo podrías conseguirlo utilizando el método `send` (aunque realmente no pasas método alguno y no guardarías em método como tal, solo su nombre) junto con otro método dentro de la clase que llame al método guardado con los nuevos parámetros; por ejemplo:

```
def a(x,y)
  x + y
end

class MiClase
  attr_reader :res

  def initialize(funcion, param1, param2)
    @fun = funcion
    @res = send(@fun, param1, param2)
  end

  def fun(param1, param2)
    send(@fun, param1, param2)
  end
end

mi_clase = MiClase.new(:a, 4, 3)

puts mi_clase.res
#=> 7

puts mi_clase.fun(2, 2)
#=> 4
```

Este código podría limpiarse un poco, pero prefiero mostrarlo así para que sea más claro. Si nos cuentas más detalle sobre *por qué* buscas este comportamiento, posiblemente podríamos ayudarte a encontrar una mejor solución.

Comment: con send me produce main.rb:19:in `<main>': undefined method `fun' for #<MiClase:0x00555c8cbcecb8 @res=7> (NoMethodError) ya que no se guarda la función

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Con el ejemplo me queda más claro lo que buscas; he actualizado mi respuesta para lograr ese comportamiento.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Agregué una nueva actualización utilizando tu código, espero te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

```
suma = lambda { |a, b| 
    return a + b
};

class MiClase

    attr_accessor :funcion
    attr_accessor :res

    def initialize(funcion, param1, param2)
        @funcion = funcion

        @res = funcion.call(param1, param2)
    end
end

clase = MiClase.new(suma, 4, 3)

puts(clase.res)
puts(clase.funcion.call(2, 2))
```

Comment: Hola zarkiel, esta respuesta ha sido reportada por la comunidad porque las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, edítala para añadir una descripción de qué es lo que hace este código y por qué solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta. Un saludo.

Comment: ...Y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre cómo funciona la comunidad en general (y así ganar una nueva medalla).

Answer (score 0):

Eso es metaprogramming:

```
class MiClase

  def initialize(method, param1, param2)
      @res = send(method, param1, param2)
  end

  def sumar(a, b)
    a+b
  end

end

miClase = MiClase.new(:sumar,4,3)
puts miClase.instance_variable_get(:@res)
```

Comment: undefined method `res' for #<MiClase:0x005564c2e9ce20 @res=7> porque no se está guardando la función que es algo que yo quería para llamarla después

Comment: Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido. ooops